# Angular - How to display data with interpolation without an array

Tags: angular

I don't need an array of data, like if you use `*ngFor=""`.
I'm wondering how I can display some JSON data without using that, as this isn't an array of JSON data, just one set of it. (single)
I've tried like `{{ user.name }}` but this doesn't work. it says: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` so it isn't being defined I assume unlike if I were to use `*ngFor=""`
As I've said, I don't need an array so ngFor won't work in this case, I need something to define the data here like that *would* but I'm not sure what you'd use.

Thank you.

Comment: if you'd like some more info, just let me know.

Comment: what response are you getting from db?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: can u console your response?

Comment: Sorry about not including it, here you go. I've made a github for it. take a look around. [github page](https://github.com/etnz1337/rust-stats)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Your variable is named `users$`, but in the template you refer to `user`. In the template you should also use `users$` (e.g. `{{users$.name}}`). Probably better if you just rename the variable in your component to `user` though.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It didn't seem to work, I need to define it somehow. As I've said if I did something like `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>` then that would work, except not how I want since that's for an array of data. What I have here is not an array. I'm not sure what to look for, on how to define "users" in my component to be used.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to display just JSON, you can use json pipe

```
{{user | json}}
```

also you need to use *ngIf incase user is undefined

```
<div *ngIf="user">
   <h1>{{user | json}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How will that help if `user` is undefined?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen hope i answered

Comment: Well, to get rid of the error, OP might as well just use `{{user?.name}}`, but since `user` is undefined, the first thing required is to figure out why it's undefined. We cannot do that without seeing more code.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Would you like to see my code? I appreciate the response, and indeed you are correct. I will note that users *would* be defined if I define it within a for loop `(*ngFor="let users of users$")` but I do not need this since it's not an array. Let me know if you'd like my code, it'll probably help you out more.